# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'input_date')

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, pagination

i'm trying to paginate the data table in which i used ajax to refresh the table without reloading the page but the input_date considered null even though its not

here's the js

```js
function reloadProjects() {
    // Make an AJAX request to get the latest project data from the server
    $.ajax({
        url: '/get-latest-projects', // Adjust the route based on your Laravel setup
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            // Update HTML with new data
            var tbody = $('.table-responsive-data2 tbody');
            tbody.empty(); // Clear existing data

            // Loop through projects and append to the tbody
            $.each(data, function (index, project) {
                // Adjust the HTML structure based on your project data
                var rowHtml = `
                    <tr class="tr">
                        <td >${project.input_date}</td>
                        <td >${project.nama_project}</td>
                        <td class="desc">${project.requestor}</td>
                        <td >${project.category_project}</td>
                        <td >
                        <span>${project.description_project}</span>
                        </td>
                        <td >${project.status}</td>
                        <td ><span class="status--process">${project.pic_project}</span></td>
                        <td >${project.eta_project}</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="table-data-feature">                                
                                <button type="button" class="item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal${project.id}" data-placement="top" title="Edit">
                                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-edit"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button class="item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete">
                                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i>
                                </button>                                
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                `;

                tbody.append(rowHtml);
            });
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        }
    });
}

// Call the function on page load or based on some trigger
$(document).ready(function () {
    reloadProjects();
});
```

here's the controller

```php
public function index()
    {
        $projects = Project::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
        return view('table', compact('projects'));

    }


    // HomeController.php
    // HomeController.php
    public function getLatestProjects()
    {
        $projects = Project::orderBy('id', 'desc')->latest()->paginate(5); // Adjust as needed
        return response()->json($projects);
    }
```

i tried to put ->get() in the controller on getLatestProject() instead it made the refresh function unable, meanwhile if i remove the get() it shows the error of Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'input_date').

thanks in advance

Comment: The browser disagrees with you. It says it's trying to read `input_date` from `project`, but `project` is `null`. I bet that the browser is correct.

Comment: i tried to `console.log(data)` and it shows the data fetched. how come the `project` is null?

Comment: Try `console.log(index, project)` inside the loop.

Comment: its a `JSON` object with several properties

Comment: i tried `console.log(index, project)` also and it shows the same data

Comment: And I bet that the last it processes is null. Publish the data or look closely.

Answer (score 1):

See the Laravel docs for [converting pagination results to JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#converting-results-to-json)

> The JSON from the paginator will include meta information such as `total`, `current_page`, `last_page`, and more. **The result records are available via the `data` key**...

You're trying to iterate these metadata fields, at least one of which has a `null` value (probably `prev_page_url`). Instead you should iterate the `data` property

```js
$.each(data.data, function(index, project) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: so it's simply it wasn't access the object required for project.. thank you

Comment: accessing `data.data` only shows the first 5 data of first page even on the next page

Comment: @zyoohwan14 that would depend on the URL you're using to make the request. For subsequent pages you should be using `data.next_page_url`. Your code only ever uses the static `'/get-latest-projects'` URL

Comment: isn't the backend API is properly configured to handle pagination and provides a next_page_url?